# Wrap pattern "using std::begin; return begin(c);" into a function

Tags: c++, c++17

I posted a C++17 version of wrapping functions for the “two-step”, on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029776/wrap-pattern-stdbegin-return-beginc-into-a-function/50028335#50028335) on StackOverflow.

It’s more than just handy to have a wrapper, as I was searching for good solutions on how to use `begin` (etc.) in a constructor initializer list, so there was no scope to add the `using` declaration to, and I could not push the function definition itself down into a nested namespace.

My point (in the SO post) is to follow [Eric Niebler’s advice](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/) that these should be function-call objects, not functions!

I’ve refined it for general reuse within a body of code, for ambient use within a library and available *from* that library for other code.

I found I needed another dummy namespace wrapper — I don’t want the `use std::begin;` to be declared in namespace `twostep`, because people who `use namespace twostep;` into their desired scope should get *only* the `Begin` symbol it creates, not `twostep::begin` née `std::begin` as well.  From my reading of the standard, it appears that `using namespace twostep` will declare all the names *declared* in `twostep`, not just those names *introduced*.

I kept the distinct (capitalized) names rather than replacing the originals, because trying to have the new symbol (found without ADL) turn around and do the lookup *with* ADL and the `using std::begin;` added in to local scope would be a horrid nightmare and a puzzle unto itself.

Unlike Eric’s rather lengthy code, I was able to use the new `inline` feature for variables to handle ODR; *and* I got SFINAE to work with the lambda function (Eric couldn’t when he wrote that), so it is rather simple now and has the makings of a good idiom worth keeping.

I wonder if it is possible to generate these lambdas?  Ideally I could have

```
inline auto Begin = detail::wrap (&std::begin);
```

because the code is totally boilerplate:  get the signature from the forwarded-to function, but accomplish the SFINAE as well??!

Note that I don’t *really* need the full power of SFINAE here:  I’m not overloading on the search for `Begin`; I’m targeting the specific `Begin` symbol I want up front because it is found as a variable, not a function.  So getting an error *somewhere* once it tries to instantiate that template is sufficient; however, I want a clean neat error (Begin has no operator()) rather than template spew.  ‘neat enough’ would be OK, if a wrapper is feasible.

Here is the code with two wrappers.  Once I’m certain it will be the final form, I’ll add the rest of them.

```
#pragma once

#include <iterator>

namespace Dlugosz::d3 {

inline namespace twostep_wrapper {
// The std:: declarations need to be in scope for the two-step functions to work,
// but we don't want them to appear as declared names in namespace twostep.  That way,
// `using namespace twostep;` will bring in Begin but not bring in begin from std.

using std::begin;
using std::end;

inline namespace twostep_inner {

inline auto Begin = [](auto&& r) ->
    decltype(begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r))) // using return type to do SFINAE
{
    return begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r));
};

inline auto End = [](auto&& r) ->
decltype(end(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r)))
{
    return end(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r));
};

} // namespace twostep_inner

} // scope wrapper

// back in namespace d3
namespace twostep = twostep_wrapper::twostep_inner;
using namespace twostep;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace Dlugosz::d3 {
  inline namespace twostep_wrapper {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    inline namespace twostep_inner {
      inline auto Begin = [](auto&& r)
      //...
```

The use of `inline` namespaces seems inappropriate.  Did you intend for the content of your `inline` namespaces to percolate up to `d3` and pollute it?  The user essentially gets access to

- `d3::begin()`, (intended?)
- `d3::Begin()`, (intended?)
- `d3::twostep_wrapper::begin()`, (user shouldn't call this)
- `d3::twostep_wrapper::Begin()`, (user shouldn't call this)
- `d3::twostep_wrapper::twostep_inner::Begin()`, (user shouldn't call this)
- `d3::twostep::Begin()`, (intended!)

as well as the `end()`/`End()` versions.

---

```
inline auto Begin = [](auto&& r) 
-> decltype(begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r)))
{
    return begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r));
};
```

C++17 provides `constexpr` lambdas.  While lambdas may evaluate in a `constexpr` context implicitly, consider being explicit.

Consider inheriting the `noexcept` specification from the function that is selected in overload resolution.

```
inline constexpr auto Begin = [](auto&& r) 
noexcept(noexcept(begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r))))
-> decltype(begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r)))
{
    return begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r));
};
```

---

You listed Niebler's blog post, but he also has a [proposal](http://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4381.html) you may want to check out.

Comment: right, the `inline` is incorrect there.  Sloppy editing when I figured out I needed the dummy wrapper, which is different from the normal pattern of just adding a name for importing as a group.

Comment: `noexcept`: yes, I should do that.  So now I repeat the body *3* times!  Time for a macro to stamp these out I guess.